# Php change date with respect to specified time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have this question.

I am using php, mysql and my files will be hosted on linux machine.

Is it possible to change the date on a different format. I mean the date should change if it is 5PM. That is if today is 28th august 2010, then after 5pm it should show 29th august 2010.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you care about timezone DST rules?

Comment: you should learn more about time zones. seems like you want to change the time based on another part of the world.

Comment: Thanks for reply @steve and @stillstanding. My only requirement is that if the time is 7PM the day should change. Is it possible? Wil check timezone and learn more about it..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you simply want to add 7 hours to current time?

```
$corrected=time() + 3600*7;
echo strftime("%d %B %Y", $corrected);
```

If you want to do this for all your code, take a look at the [PHP time zone configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) and [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

If you want to set your timezone on a server-wide basis, you'll probably find plenty of answers on ServerFault.com, such as [**Setting time zone on Linux (ubuntu)**](https://serverfault.com/questions/31470/setting-time-zone-on-linux-ubuntu)

See also

- [PHP ini date.timezone? Server or client location time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251780/php-ini-date-timezone-server-or-client-location-time-zone)
- [PHP, how to set timezone??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545164/php-how-to-set-timezone)
- [Dealing with timezones in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346770/dealing-with-timezones-in-php)

Comment: Thanks paul. Actually it is required because i am using arabic time and the day changes after 7PM